# Jquery reveal string on click ( tel:)

Tags: jquery

Trying to hide phone numbers by default, forcing uses to "click to reveal". On top of that adding relevant event tracking so we can track clicks using Google analytics Event tracking.

I've tried this script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var phonenumbers = [];
    $(".phonenumber").each(function(i) {
        phonenumbers.push($(this).text());
        var newcontent = $(this).text().substr(0, $(this).text().length - 4)
        $(this).text(newcontent);
        $(this).bind("click", function() {
            if ($(this).text() == phonenumbers[i]) {
                $(this).text(phonenumbers[i].substr(0, phonenumbers[i].length - 4));
            } else {
            $(".phonenumber").each(function(x) {
                if ($(this).text() == phonenumbers[x]) {
                   $(this).text(phonenumbers[x].substr(0, phonenumbers[x].length - 4));
                }
            });            
            $(this).text(phonenumbers[i]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Which hides the last 4 digits by default using this format :

`<a class="phone" href="tel:04480252578">044 802 52578</a>`

But id like to use a completely different anchor text,  hiding the entire phone number until the new anchor text is clicked.

Comment: how much do you pay?

Comment: jQuery + ajax calls to get number and track count

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code you've tried. That is really what people are looking for when you come here for help. Otherwise your question is going to get down voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't need AJAX for tracking; if you're trying to track it with something like Google Analytics, you can simply trigger an event in analytics when the reveal is clicked.

There are several ways to do this, some might try hiding the phone number behind an absolute positioned element that says "reveal". I chose to just use the href to get the number and replace the text of the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        // Use one instead of on so that you're only preventing default once
        $('a[href^="tel:"]').one('click', function(e){

             e.preventDefault();

             // Gets the string from the href and removes anything not a digit
             var phone_number = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\D/g,'');

             // 044 802 52578
             var phone_formatted = phone_number.substr(0, 3);
             phone_formatted += ' ' + phone_number.substr(3, 3);
             phone_formatted += ' ' + phone_number.substr(6);

             // Trigger your analytics event
             // ga is used by Google Analytics, 
             // it must be loaded before you do this
             ga('send', {
                hitType: 'event',
                eventCategory: 'Interaction',
                eventAction: 'click-reveal-phone',      
                eventLabel: 'Phone Number Revealed',
                eventValue: 0,
                nonInteraction: true
            });
            // The above could be written like this as well
            // ga('send', 'event', 'Interaction', 'click-reveal-phone', 'Phone Number Revealed');


             $(this).text(phone_formatted);

    })

})
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvf786gk/).

Comment: Thanks so much for that code,  I've actually got it working with wordpress removing $(document).ready(function(){ and using instead 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

Does exactly what i need :) Thank you for your time.

Comment: Out of interest, where you have commented //trigger your analytics event.  Is there further code needed ?

Comment: Yes, that was just something I threw in based on a comment on your original question. If you are using Google Analytics, look into Event Tracking here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events. With Event Tracking you can alert analytics to custom events, then, in the analytics dashboard, you can create goals based on them. I'll update my code with a commented out example. Also accept my answer so I improve my reputation! :)

Comment: Ah that would be great if you could update with an example,  I have also updated the answer to accepted :)  Thanks for also training me on how Stackoverflow works,  I didnt even realise there was an Accept answer button :)

Comment: Sure thing, it's a great place and a great resource.

Comment: Thanks alot,  it sure is.  I  get an error with the latest edit however. "ReferenceError: ga is not defined"

Comment: Yep, ga needs to be defined. In the analytics tracking code Google provides, that you place into your page, that defines the ga variable. I usually place it in my footer template in WordPress projects, and in my javascript file I check for it before using it like: if (typeof(ga) !== 'undefined') { then trigger the event}

Comment: Ah got it,  thanks very much.  :) Thanks again.  Have a great week.

Comment: In my example, the e.preventDefault() prevents that from happening on the initial click. It works as expected in the jsFiddle I linked to. I can help to debug your code if you can find a way to show it to me. Maybe create a jsFiddle of your own and paste the link?